# Monitor for when a lockfile disappears

Tags: batch-file, file-monitoring

We have an application that creates a lockfile, and while that lockfile exists, you can't operate on other files within the application.  So, copying data files, extracting them to read, etc can't be done while it exists.

We were using a workaround that uses ShadowCopy (VSS) to allow us to ignore the lockfile, copy the files, and read them.  Now we've run into an issue at one of our locations, where VSS doesn't play nicely on a Virtual Machine and throws errors.

How do I perform realtime monitoring of a Server directory, in order to perform an action as soon as a lockfile no longer exists, using only native commands or utilities?

> EDIT: Based on a comment that was removed, I'm thinking it should go something like this, in a batch executed daily:
>
> ```
> :WaitLoop 
> IF NOT EXIST "path\to\app.db$-lock" TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK (
> ROBOCOPY "path\to" "path\to\Files" *.V2$ *.DA$ *.DI$ *.IX$ /E /XO /MT:16 > "path\to\Files\robocopy.log" & GOTO BreakLoop  )
> GOTO WaitLoop
> :BreakLoop
> EXIT
> ```

Comment: The key part for me was the `TIMEOUT`.  Nothing seemed relevant in the suggestions when I submitted the question, and keywords like "cmd monitor directory" were just way too broad for an internet search.  I knew it was something simple I was missing.  Thanks for helping in spite of such a noob question.  If you wanna make it a full-fledged answer, I'll give credit.

Comment: BTW: The code posted by you is not valid. I posted in a comment deleted by someone else (not me) `IF EXIST "path\to\app.db$-lock" %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 1 /NOBREAK >nul & goto WaitLoop` The next line should begin with `%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe` and the other three lines should be deleted. Batch files should contain fully qualified file names to reduce the number of file system accesses to a minimum, especially on doing that in a loop. Other processes usually access the file system at the same time too.

Answer (score 0):

This is different than a lot of monitoring questions I found, because it's looking for a file to **not** be there.  The /MON of robocopy won't help in that case, for instance, since as far as I can tell, it monitors all changes.

This answer worked, modified slightly.
https://superuser.com/a/983625/117443

```
:waitloop
IF NOT EXIST "path\to\app.db$-lock" GOTO waitloopend
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK >nul
goto waitloop
:waitloopend
ROBOCOPY "path\to" "path\to\Files" *.V2$ *.DA$ *.DI$ *.IX$ /E /XO /MT:16 > "path\to\robocopy.log"
```